# Minted vs matlab-prettifier for thesis

Tags: listings, minted, sourcecode, matlab, matlab-prettifier

I am writing my PhD thesis now for which I need to list snippets of source-code within the main text and full listings in the appendix.

I did my coding entirely in MATLAB using advanced constructs and modern toolboxes.

I see that there are two main candidates with strengths in s MATLAB specific typesetting.

The first one is the `matlab-prettifier` package and the second being `minted`. I am asking this question to know which one is more suitable in the modern day?

The matlab-prettifier was last updated in 2014 June whereas minted was last updated in September of 2017. Furthermore, pygments is supposed to be superior than anything else out there?

In this context, which would you recommend for a PhD thesis written in the middle of 2018?

Comment: Full disclosure: I'm the author of `matlab-prettifier`. Section 2 of the [documentation](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/matlab-prettifier/matlab-prettifier.pdf) compares the package and pygments. Check it out; it will help you make an informed decision.